# Datatable fixedcolumn with dynamic height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable, datatables

Everything works good until I click on `<tr>` (remove row). Height of table is changed but fixed column have always the same. Problem is that I can't use bottom scrollbar after removing row (part under fixed column)

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/rn68jqth/20/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redraw the table after you hide it.
http://jsfiddle.net/rn68jqth/42/

```
$(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable(
        {
          scrollY: "300px",
          scrollX: true,
          scrollCollapse: true,
          paging: false,
          ordering: false,
          bInfo: false,
          searching: false,
          fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 1,
            heightMatch: 'auto'
          },
        });

  $('tr').on('click', function() {
  let index =  $(this).data('id');
    $('.tr_'+index).hide(function()
    {
        table.draw();
    });
  });


});
```

Comment: After redraw you have to bind again click event - otherwise you can't remove more rows

Answer (score 1):

You can also destroy the table and recreate also instead of hide use display none.
http://jsfiddle.net/rn68jqth/67/

```
$(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable(
        {
          scrollY: "300px",
          scrollX: true,
          scrollCollapse: true,
          paging: false,
          ordering: false,
          bInfo: false,
          searching: false,
          fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 1,
            heightMatch: 'auto'
          },
        });

  $('tr').on('click', function() {
  var index =  $(this).data('id');
    //$('.tr_'+index).hide('fast');
    $('.tr_'+index).attr("style","display:none;");
    $('#example').DataTable().destroy();
    $('#example').DataTable({
    scrollY: "300px",
          scrollX: true,
          scrollCollapse: true,
          paging: false,
          ordering: false,
          bInfo: false,
          searching: false,
          fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 1,
            heightMatch: 'auto'
          },
    });
  });
});
```